# Django ordering in admin

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    fabric = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    color = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    supplier = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Import(models.Model):
    packing_list = models.ForeignKey(PackingList)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

In `admin.py` I have the following code:

```
class ImportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def fabric(self,obj):
        return obj.article.fabric
    def color(self,obj):
        return obj.article.color
    def supplier(self,obj):
        return obj.article.supplier

    list_display = ['id', 'fabric', 'color', 'supplier','quantity','comment'] 
    search_fields = ['packing_list__name']
```

and in my admin panel I would like to sort the fields by `fabric`.

I tried doing `ordering = ('fabric', )` but I am unable to do that because `fabric` is not an attribute of `Import`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: In general, you can't order by the result of a a method on the instance or the model admin. However, in this case, since you really want to order by the `fabric` field of the `article` foreign key, it is possible to override the model admin's queryset and use `order_by('article__fabric')`.

Comment: I added this in `ImportAdmin` class:

`def sorted_fabric(self, request):
        query_set = super(ImportAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return query_set.order_by('article__fabric')`


but this method does not work

Comment: The method should be called `get_queryset`, not `sorted_fabric`. And you should call `super(ImportAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)`.

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you